# copy-paste file from jenkins directory to home directory using FileOperations plugin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I have created a jenkins file that above everything else that is does, in the end will copy paste a .jar file from the jenkins target directory to home directory. I tried many options like sudo cp and sudo visudo to give jenkins privilleges but that didn't work, besides it's not safe from security perspective.

Then I tried to install the FileOperations [plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/#file-operations-plugin).

```
stage("Copy the created .jar file to home directory for docker deployment"){
    steps{
    fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
                        flattenFiles: false,
                        includes: '*.jar',
                        targetLocation: "home/user"
        )])
    }
}
```

Output:

> 18:27:37  File Copy Operation: 
> 18:27:37  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline_production/my.jar 
> 18:27:37  FATAL: /home/user/my.jar

I quite miss what is going wrong with this configuration and does no succeed. Appreciate any suggestion.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355195/10623444)

Answer (score 0):

You can check and provide the full path of the jar file where it exists and check if it is available.

```
 fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
                        flattenFiles: false,
                        includes: '*.jar',  // Give full path where .jar file exists
                        targetLocation: "home/user"
        )])
```

Another option could be just use a `cp` command of shell to copy files :

```
sh "cp -f <Source path> <Destination>"
sh "cp -f *.jar home/user/"
```

You could also execute the commands by changing the directory:

```
    steps{
       dir("<Path of your jar file>"){
               fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
                        flattenFiles: false,
                        includes: '*.jar',
                        targetLocation: "home/user"
        )])
           OR
        sh "cp -f *.jar home/user/"

        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Hey, actually the 'cp' command needs the sudo privileges. So it won't be executed without sudo. Also I tried the option of ```sudo cp``` but this return tty error no response.

Comment: @NikSp : Is your jar file available at the location?

Comment: Yes it's available on /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline_production/my.jar  as my output states in SO

Comment: @NikSp did you try by giving the full path.``includes: "//var//lib//jenkins//workspace//pipeline_production//*.jar",``. You can also execute this in the ``dir("//var//lib//jenkins//workspace//pipeline_production") { fileoperations ..}``

Comment: Yeah but I didn't try it with double slashes ```//```..I used single slashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233515/discussion-between-altaf-and-niksp).