# Copy a file to a different directory during Jenkins build on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to do something that seems pretty basic but is giving me a lot of trouble. I am trying to copy the jar file that is built into a different directory but the build keep failing on that step. Here is my Jenkinsfile and the "Copy" step at the bottom is causing the failure.

```groovy
    pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage("Clean Up"){
          steps{
            deleteDir()
          }
        }
        stage("Clone Repo"){
          steps {
            bat "git clone https://github.com/CBoton/spring-boot-hello-world.git"
          }
        }
        stage("Build"){
          steps {
            dir("spring-boot-hello-world") {
              bat "mvn clean install"
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Test") {
          steps {
            dir("spring-boot-hello-world") {
              bat "mvn test"
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Package") {
            steps {
              dir("spring-boot-hello-world") {
                bat "mvn package"
            }
            }
            post {
              success {
                dir("spring-boot-hello-world") {
                archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Copy"){
          steps {
            dir("spring-boot-hello-world"){
              bat ("copy target/*.jar C:\\Users\\Curti\\Downloads")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How I have it now produces the following error

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\spring\spring-boot-hello-world>copy target/*.jar C:\Users\Curti\Downloads 


The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I have tried many variations for the path but can't get it to work. This is starting to drive me crazy because it seems like it would be so simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355195/2627018

Answer (score 0):

@ycr, I was trying to do it without plugins but ultimately the File Operations plugin worked, thank you. My new copy step looks like

```
stage("Copy"){
      steps {
        fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
        excludes: '',
        flattenFiles: false,
        includes: '**/*.jar',
        targetLocation: "C:\\output"
        )])
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a powershell build step or post-build action and use that to copy the items:

```
Copy-Item -Path "target\*.jar" -Destination "C:\Users\Curti\Downloads" -Recurse
```

[image]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.4 and https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/